# Cassandra Data Model without secondary index

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE tablea (
    hour text,
    key_mod int,
    processed int,
    column1 bigint,
    column2 biginit,
    column3 biginit,
    PRIMARY KEY ((event_hour, key_mod, processed), item_id, variation_id) 

CREATE INDEX processed_idx ON tablea (processed);
```

processed takes two values - 1 means processed 0 means not processed

```
SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE hour=? AND key_mod=? AND p1='N' LIMIT 300;
```

This is creating a huge secondary index and I have a feeling its causing frequent gc as well.

My access pattern looks like

1. Get a small batch of unprocessed records
2. Process them
3. Mark the records in the batch as “processed”

What's the best way to model this table? We can't add processed to the clustering columns because we won't be able to update it. We are running out of ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation makes it look like you are trying to use Cassandra as a queue (of unprocessed events) and that is an anti-pattern (you can see another answer of mine to a similar situation: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66153721/12811606)).

Having the status as either a partition column or clustering column will make updating it impossible so a delete and probably a read before write will be also required, and that apart from the overhead will create tombstones.

Also as you mentioned yourself having an index on a 2 value field will create problems.

I will not copy paste my other answer here but I am pretty sure that the contents could solve your problem here too (using something like Kafka seems to be what you need).
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense.